# Delete by error /bin folder compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deleted  the folder bin inside of a compute engine instance by mistake. So I can't connect the virtual machine.

What can I do to connect?

Comment: Basically, you have destroyed your instance. You can save the disk (snapshot or image) and mount on a new instance to recover data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your best shoot is to mount the damaged disk into another VM and try to recover your files. You can try the following steps to regain access to your files:

1. Take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_zonal_snapshot) of the VM disk.
2. Create a [disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restoresnapshottonew) from the snapshot.
3. Create a rescue VM using the same OS version of the damaged one.
4. [Add](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) the disk created from snapshot to the rescue VM
5. Go to your rescue vm instance via SSH
6. Type and enter the command to create a mountpoint:

   `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/rescue`
7. Type and enter the command to mount the damaged disk:

   `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disks/rescue`

Now you are able to access to the files of the damaged VM under the mountpoint